# Add a String to a value in an Array Powershell

Tags: arrays, string, powershell, powershell-2.0

I have got Strings in an array which are the names of groups. Now I would like to modify those values and connect an other String to the beginning of this String

```
$Groups = Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership $User $GroupArray = @()

foreach ($Group in $Groups)
{
$GroupArray += ($Group | select name)
} 
echo $("Domain\" + $GroupArray[0])
```

This prints something like:

```
Domain\@{name=Domain Users}
```

However I would like to get something like:

```
Domain\Domain Users
```

Comment: `"Domain\$(GroupArray[0].Name)"`

Comment: since you used `Select-Object Name` you have an object with a property named `Name`. it seems that you want to have JUST the value from the prop. if that is the case, then change that to `Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name` to get just the value.

Comment: Why not arraylist? Then Arraylist.add(value).. It seems a lot easier to deal with.

Comment: The easiest way is to just set a variable equal to the foreach loop and output the data you want within the loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change it to arraylist if you wish to add all the values:

```
$Groups = Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership $User

$arraylist = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList
foreach ($Group in $Groups)
{
$arraylist.Add($Group.Name) | Out-Null
} 

$arraylist
```

PS: You can display the result collating with the Domain however you want; I have not touched that section. Hope it helps.

Comment: @Andr0mega: Happy to help. Enjoy coding :)